# How to handle refactor with south (django)?

Tags: python, database, django, migration, django-south

I have installed south and make some migrations. Now there's a 'migrations' directory in the folder app. My question is: when I am refactoring models, which entries in the migration directory files I must apply the changes? I think some entries are related directly with the database schema, and others with the code itself. I couldn't fina an answer to this in the south docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the changes to your models then run `python manage.py schemamigration yourapp --auto`. This will create the migrations for you (you'll see a new file in your migrations directory every time you do this process).

Sometimes you really need to edit a migration manually, but you should try and avoid it. Particularly if you have already run the migration (the south app keeps a record of which migrations have been run so it knows the state of your database).

South is designed to support moving between different versions of your code without breaking your database. Each migration file in the migrations directory represents a snapshot of your code (specifically a snapshot of your `models.py`). You migrate from version to version by running `python manage.py migrate yourapp version_no`

Comment: Thank you, it handled the problem itself.